# Нижний регистр в autocomplit

Tags: javascript, java, autocomplete

Всем привет, сделал autocomplit для своего веб приложения, проблема вот в чем, в БД все данные `kiz` с большой буквы (ИК62), можно ли как-то сделать так, что бы в `input` я вводил с маленькой буквы (ик...), но оно мне показывало варианты с большой?

Метод в дао:

```
public ArrayList<String> getDistinctKiz(String frameWork) {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        String data;
        try {
           // ps = connection.prepareStatement("select kiz from tbl_temp where kiz like ? order by kiz");
            ps = connection.prepareStatement("select distinct kiz from clippersql.mv_vp44150_distinct_kiz_svi where kiz like ? order by kiz limit 10");
            ps.setString(1, frameWork + "%");
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) {
                data = rs.getString("kiz");
                list.add(data);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Сервлет:

```
String term = request.getParameter("term");
  System.out.println("Data from ajax call " + term);
  /*Преобразование списка кизов в json*/
  Vp44150sqlDao vp44150sqlDao = new Vp44150sqlDao();
  ArrayList<String> list = vp44150sqlDao.getDistinctKiz(term);
  String searchList = new Gson().toJson(list);
  response.getWriter().write(searchList);
```

И непосредственно сам скрипт:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $(function() {

         $("#kiz").autocomplete({     
             source : function(request, response) {
                 //$("#loading").show();
                 $(".ui-helper-hidden-accessible").empty();

               $.ajax({
                    url : "AutocompleteKizController",
                    type : "GET",
                    data : {
                           term : request.term
                    },
                    dataType : "json",
                    success : function(data) {
                          response(data);
                       //   $("#loading").hide();
                    }
```

Comment: Можно поправить SQL запрос, чтобы игнорировать регистр, например, так: `select distinct kiz from clippersql.mv_vp44150_distinct_kiz_svi where lower(kiz) like lower(?) order by kiz limit 10`

Comment: спасибо, можете оформить как ответ, проголосую

Comment: еще в JS, можно использовать метод `toUpperCase()` Синтаксис: `var STRING = string.toUpperCase ()`

Comment: а как именно его правильно применить? вот с скриптом пока у меня явно слабее чем с sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно просто поправить SQL запрос, чтобы игнорировать регистр, например, так:

```
select
  distinct kiz
from
  clippersql.mv_vp44150_distinct_kiz_svi
where lower(kiz) like lower(?)
order by kiz limit 10
```

Comment: Идея одна из худших. В такой реализации будут игнорироваться все индексы. Самое правильное - это установить на поле DATATYPE/COLLATION, которые игнорируют различие регистра

Comment: @AntonShchyrov добавьте ответ, если считаете, что есть лучшее решение